# Include rack oauth2 in rails 3 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0

I want my Rails Application to act as a oauth2 token provider.

I am relatively new to ruby development, however it seems to me that developing based on Rack is beneficial for such scenarios.

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper - Gem for easy setup your app as oauth2 provider.